# How to read properties/attributes of file in j2me

Tags: file, java-me

I have googled this for two days now but I can't get the answer.

How can I get the properties/attributes of a file(e.g mine.mp3) in j2me. Am looking for the normal file attributes such as name, size, date modified and most importantly-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [FileConnection](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/android/io/file/FileConnection.html) class in J2ME. This document will provide all the details regarding your requirement.

By using this class you can fetch a file's attribute like [fileSize()](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-D69FC49D-783E-45CE-80D4-7A9F3EE08B2A/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#fileSize%28%29), [getPath()](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-D69FC49D-783E-45CE-80D4-7A9F3EE08B2A/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#getPath%28%29), [lastModified()](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-D69FC49D-783E-45CE-80D4-7A9F3EE08B2A/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#lastModified%28%29) etc

Comment: Thanks for this, though from the documentation, I see that there's no way to get file type :( I guess I'll just have to splice the name and use the extension to guess the file type(not fool-proof)

Comment: what do you mean by file-type ?

Comment: e.g pic.png would have a file(mime) type of image/png.